# ASP.NET : Connection String not working IIS - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

So I have a WebAPI project with Individual Accounts, and I published it to a folder.

After that, I added a new website in IIS Manager. I created a new connection string with SQL Server Settings:

- Server : WINDOWSHOST\WINSQLSERVER
- Database : Database2
- Credentials : Use Windows Integrated Security

> Server=WINDOWSHOST\WINSQLSERVER;Database=Database2;Intergrated Security=true

If I use WINDOWSHOST\WINSQLSERVER and IntergratedSecurity in SQL Server Management Studio, I can log in successfully, but trying to create an account gives me an internal server error

Response from server : [image]

Comment: can you put some errorcodes, exceptions and describe more. your question is not conclusive.

Comment: Are you using impersonation on your web.config? Also, is your application pool running some credentials? Connecting to SQL Server Mgmt Studio is different when passing through IIS to connect to the database.

Comment: @Angelo I'm relatively new to setting up SQL servers, so I'm not sure

Comment: Do you give user name and password when logging in to sql studio?

Comment: @RyanVancityGosling - how are you testing that your web api is correctly configured? Are you able to make an API call (create a basic api first that will just return a string). And from there, you can try to add some codes that will make some calls to the database.

Comment: @Angelo The Get method in the default Values controller returns a string

Comment: You have to Give permissions to IIS APPPOOL\mysite in SQL server

Comment: @Usman Did that, still not working

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in your api call, and see the full details of the error? Internal Server Error at times says that something in your API was broken, and may not necessarily mean outright that you are unable to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: Just to see whether we do have issue with connection, in your IIS, locate the AppPool being used by the site. Go to Advanced Settings and find the Identity property. Click on the placeholder for the identity and on the Application Pool identity popup, select Custom account and enter your username and password there. Re-test the API call that connects to your DB.

Comment: @Angelo I uploaded a screen grab of the response. What username and password should I enter?

Comment: No, go to the IIS itself. There's an AppPool for the application you deployed. Check the advanced settings as I have mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, I got that but what username and password should enter? The SQL server username and password? @Angelo

Comment: Is there no more info on the error in the Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: @RyanVancityGosling - use the windows credentials that you have to login to the machine itself.

Answer (score 0):

Default IIS does not support using Windows Integrated Security. these are steps to enable windows authentication

- Select your website in IIS Manager.
- Double-click the Authentication icon under the IIS header.
- Right-click on Windows Authentication and select Enable.